# Split unicode string into 300 byte chunks without destroying characters

Tags: python, string, utf-8

I want to split `u"an arbitrary unicode string"` into chunks of say 300 bytes without destroying any characters. The strings will be written to a socket that expects utf8 using `unicode_string.encode("utf8")`. I don't want to destroy any characters. How would I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

UTF-8 is designed for this.

```
def split_utf8(s, n):
    """Split UTF-8 s into chunks of maximum length n."""
    while len(s) > n:
        k = n
        while (ord(s[k]) & 0xc0) == 0x80:
            k -= 1
        yield s[:k]
        s = s[k:]
    yield s
```

Not tested.  But you find a place to split, then backtrack until you reach the beginning of a character.

However, if a user might ever want to see an individual chunk, you may want to split on grapheme cluster boundaries instead.  This is significantly more complicated, but not intractable.  For example, in `"é"`, you *might* not want to split apart the `"e"` and the `"´"`.  Or you might not care, as long as they get stuck together again in the end.

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work. Though end users will see the chunks I find this solution good enough. Upon some quick reading grapheme cluster boundaries seemed very demanding to implement. I don't need it right now. Is `(ord(s[k]) & 0xc0) == 0x80` the same as `"\x80" <= s[k] <= "\xBF"`? I do find this neatly crafted

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.  I'm somewhat used to writing UTF-8 handling code in C, which explains the style.  Use whatever style you feel best.

Answer (score 5):

UTF-8 has a special property that all continuation characters are `0x80`–`0xBF` (start with bits 10). So just make sure you don't split right before one.

Something along the lines of:

```
def split_utf8(s, n):
    if len(s) <= n:
        return s, None
    while ord(s[n]) >= 0x80 and ord(s[n]) < 0xc0:
        n -= 1
    return s[0:n], s[n:]
```

should do the trick.

Note: it is to be done on the encoded value, i.e. `str` in python 2 and `bytes` in python 3. The python 3 `bytes.__getitem__` also includes the call to `ord` already, so just drop it there.

Comment: Does not work on Python 3, where `len(s)` gives you the number of Unicode characters in the string, while `n` is the desired number of UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @RogerDahl, it works exactly the same in python 2 and python 3—in both cases it shall be called *after* `.encode()`, and `len(bytes)` returns number of bytes (added note to the answer to make that clear).

Comment: Thanks, Jan, but can't pass `bytes` into the function because `s[n]` then returns an `int` which `ord` can't handle.

Comment: @RogerDahl, ok, that's somewhat counter-intuitive, but the solution is simple. Since `ord` converts a character or byte to an integer, and you already have an integer, just remove the `ord`.

Answer (score 2):

Tested.

```
def split_utf8(s , n):
    assert n >= 4
    start = 0
    lens = len(s)
    while start < lens:
        if lens - start <= n:
            yield s[start:]
            return # StopIteration
        end = start + n
        while '\x80' <= s[end] <= '\xBF':
            end -= 1
        assert end > start
        yield s[start:end]
        start = end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the utf-8 representation of your chars are only 2 byte long than you should be safe to split the unicode string into chunks of 150 chars (this should be true for most european encodings). But utf-8 is variable-width encoding. So might might split the unicode string into single characters, convert each char to utf-8 and fill your buffer until you reached the max chunk-size...this might be inefficient and a problem if high-throughput is an must...

Comment: There will be more that european encodings. Both chinese and japanese will definately be represented. High throughput is not required. I was hoping there was a prettier solution though.

Comment: Well, utf-8 converted chars are at most 4 byte long. So junks of 75 chars times 4 makes 300 byte -in order to be on the very safe side.

Answer (score -1):

Use unicode encoding which by design have fixed length of each character, for example `utf-32`:

```
>>> u_32 = u'Юникод'.encode('utf-32')
>>> u_32
'\xff\xfe\x00\x00.\x04\x00\x00=\x04\x00\x008\x04\x00\x00:\x04\x00\x00>\x04\x00\x
004\x04\x00\x00'
>>> len(u_32)
28
>>> len(u_32)%4
0
>>>
```

After encoding you can send chunk of any size (size must be multiple of 4 bytes) without destroying characters

Comment: This is not possible as the server expects UTF-8