# Split string by byte length in Python

Tags: python, oracle

I have a situation where I need to insert more than 4000 characters into an Oracle VARCHAR and was advised against using CLOB.  The proposed solution was to split it into 2 columns, 4000 each, and 8000 should be enough.  I made the code dynamic so could handle X number of columns for reuse.  It worked great, passed testing, etc, until it was deployed and someone copied and pasted from a Microsoft product and it broke because there was more than 4000 bytes generated in the function.  I hadn't considered unicode.

I tried several ideas to solve this before settling on one where I start with 4000 chars, and if the byte length is over 4000, remove a character and check the byte length again.  It works, but I wonder if there is a better solution.  The function also changes the column names from 'column' to 'column1', 'column2', ...etc.

```
 text = data[key]
 index = 1
 while text:
     length = 4000
     while len(text[0:length].encode('utf-8')) > 4000:
          length -= 1
     data['{}{}'.format(key, index)] = text[0:length]
     text = text[length:]
     index += 1
 del data[key]
```

Comment: [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043463/split-unicode-string-into-300-byte-chunks-without-destroying-characters) has a similar solution to yours, but it may have some other features you would find helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your advice against CLOBs was current or whether it was based on old information about accessing LOBs using locators.

The best practice for "small" CLOBs in cx_Oracle is to represent them as strings: your code will be simple and still efficient.  See the example https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py

Another solution is to use a recent version of Oracle DB that supports 32K VARCHAR2.

Comment: He had many reasons from how it's stored, how it's backed up, to a list of problems he encountered over the years with LOBs.  Maybe that is different now, idk, but he isn't budging.  I like the 32K idea, but the DB is setup for 4k.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up combining [G. Andersons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7835267/g-anderson) [link](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py) with my code.  It's more efficient in that it doesn't encode for every length check.

```
    encoded_text = data[key].encode('utf-8')
    index = 1
    while encoded_text:
        length = min(4000, len(encoded_text))
        if len(encoded_text) > 4000:
            while (encoded_text[length] & 0xc0) == 0x80:
                length -= 1
        data['{}{}'.format(key, index)] = encoded_text[:length].decode('utf-8')
        encoded_text = encoded_text[length:]
        index += 1
    del data[key]
```

I also toyed with the idea of using `encode('unicode-escape')` to get around the unicode issue, but that could potentially more than double my string length.